# Partial boot after replacing SATA controller

Tags: windows-7, boot, sata

I am just a hobbyist who has had pretty good success dealing with computer issues by finding good instructions, following them and researching troubleshooting when something didn't work. So when an acquaintance gave me her computer that wouldn't boot, I quickly traced it to a fritzing  on board SATA controller. I disabled it and installed a generic PCI replacement. (ASMEDIA ASM1062 chip) I wasn't surprised when the first boot gave me the "Repair Installation" prompt and the automatic attempt failed. I've had this issue with 2 motherboard and 3 controller replacements and only once did the automatic process help. So like I did the other times, I used dism from a Windows DVD to "inject" the included drivers, for which dism reported success. In the other situations, this had been all that was required.

But this time at the point were the 3 little colored dots appear and start to swirl above "starting Windows" the computer reboots. I let it happen twice in case anything was being repaired internally. But it wasn't. So I started the computer in safe mode and it crapped out at classpnp.sys twice. Research just tells me that this indicates a "hardware problem". The card's bios correctly identifies the attached drives at boot. So the simplest way I could think of to evaluate it was to boot a Linux rescue CD. The rescue CD had no problems identifying and working with new controller. So it seems very unlikely to me that the issue is with the actual hardware.

In researching I found the suggestion to boot in IDE mode, which the controller purports to support. The chip manufacturer website (https://www.asmedia.com.tw/product/415Yq4aSx1hz4Iu5/58dYQ8bxZ4UR9wG5) provides absolutely no documentation but purports to support IDE mode. The driver CD includes only one readme which presumes a booted and operating Windows environment. Not surprisingly, their "contact us" does not respond to a simple shmuck like me with a problem. The card was just something quick and easy I grabbed off eBay and the seller doesn't seem interested in providing an actual manufacturer for the card. Other searches gave me only results claiming that the card supported the mode but nowhere could I find instructions on how to switch it. So I can't figure out how to get the controller into this mode. I tried re-enabling the onboard controller and switching it to IDE mode in hopes that it might somehow "cascade" to the installed controller. The controller bios screen still said ahci mode and windows would not boot and in Linux all it did was disable the mouse. (Little puzzled by that. Guess it sets up some kind of port conflict?)

I ran the "Repair installation" option from a Windows DVD (even making sure to get the same version though this shouldn't matter). I let it run 3 times and when I examined the details, all the tests reported 0x0 so I don't even know what it is having an issue with.

I understand the desire to respond with "Just go get a different card". But for reasons I don't want to get into this just doesn't a good option for me. So I am just hoping someone will provide me with new troubleshooting tools beyond the ones I already have tried and I might add to my toolbox for the future.

Thx